# RIP Peter Allan Fields, Star Trek screenwriter and producer

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

**Peter Allan Fields,** the screenwriter responsible for some of the most poignant and powerful episodes of Star Trek TNG and Star Trek DS9, died this week.

Credits included the multi-award winning *[TNG: The Inner Light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inner_Light_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))* as well as *TNG: Cost of Living*, *TNG: Half a Life*, *DS9: The Dogs of War*, *DS9: For the Uniform* and *[DS9: In the Pale Moonlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Pale_Moonlight)*, widely regarded as the single best episode of the show.

[image]

In his earlier career, he served as a Marine in Korea (allegedly [lying about his age to allow him to join at the age of 16](https://twitter.com/writergeekrhw/status/1141559327829811202)), became a POW and was released when his captors found out his real age. After graduating law school on the GI Bill, he provided writing talent for numerous shows ranging from *Man from UNCLE* and *The Six Million Dollar Man* through to *Knight Rider* and *Xena: Warrior Princess*.

Comment: Wow, what a legacy!  *Inner Light* and *Half a Life* are superb Trek outings.  As for *In The Pale Moonlight* , that is  IMHO, the darkest outing in Trek history (in a very good way).  RIP.

Comment: @HelbentIV - Yup. He wrote the two best episodes of both series